# Openstack fails to launch new instances with status ERROR

Tags: openstack, permission-denied, openstack-nova

I was following the tutorials on Openstack (Stein) docs website to launch an instance on my provider network. I am using networking option 2. I run the following command to create the instance, replacing `PROVIDER_NET_ID` with my provider network interface id.

```
openstack server create --flavor m1.nano --image cirros \
  --nic net-id=PROVIDER_NET_ID --security-group default \
  --key-name mykey provider-instance1
```

I run `openstack server list` to check the status of my instance. It shows a status of `ERROR`.
I checked the `/var/log/nova/nova-compute.log` on my compute node (I only have one compute node) and came across the following error.

```
ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6
995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default]
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] Instance failed to spawn: PermissionError:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/nova/instances/19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942'
```

However, logs before this error in the log file seem like everything was okay before this error occured.

```
2022-05-23 12:40:21.011 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942]
Attempting claim on node compute1: memory 64 MB, disk 1 GB, vcpus 1 CPU
2022-05-23 12:40:21.019 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] Total memory: 3943 MB, used: 512.00 MB
2022-05-23 12:40:21.020 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] memory limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2022-05-23 12:40:21.020 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] Total disk: 28 GB, used: 0.00 GB
2022-05-23 12:40:21.021 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] disk limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2022-05-23 12:40:21.024 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] Total vcpu: 4 VCPU, used: 0.00 VCPU
2022-05-23 12:40:21.025 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] vcpu limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
2022-05-23 12:40:21.028 9627 INFO nova.compute.claims 
[req-0a1a6ddf-edc7-4987-a018-32af7b6a29b6 995cce48094442b4b29f3fb665219408 
429965cc45a743a5b00f3a1bd098e1ab - default default] 
[instance: 19a6c859-5dde-4ed3-9010-4d93ebe9a942] Claim successful on node compute1
```

Anyone have any ideas one what I may be doing wrong?
I'll be thankful.

Comment: Please don't do that. It looks like there is a permissions problem. It could be simple directory permissions; what are the owner/group in `/var/lib/nova/instances`? Under what uid is the `nova-compute` service running?

Comment: Alternately, if you're on a RHEL-derived distribution, it could be an [selinux](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/linux/what-is-selinux) issue. If that's the case, you would see `AVC` messages in `/var/log/audit`.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and the owner/group of `/var/lib/nova/instances` is `root`. The nova-compute is running under 'nova' user.

Comment: Is `/var/lib/nova/instances` mounted from a shared storage to enable live-migration? If that is the case you'll have to modify the permissions so the directory is owned by nova (we use it like that). But in general, if nova service runs as user nova then the respective directory should also be owned by user nova. BTW, Stein is a pretty old release, have you tried a newer release?